# existence 3-regualar sub graph in 6- regular graph.

Tags: graph-theory

I want prove that:

**6-regular** graph with even vertices have **3-regular** sub-graph.

if fact there is a 6-regular graph whit n vertexes that n is even. we want create a 3-regular sub-graph for it.

Comment: Does the $6$-regular graph have to be connected?

Comment: no, it may be not connected.

Comment: Does the subgraph have to span all vertices, and is it induced?

Comment: yeah it have to span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disjoint union of two $K_7$'s satisfies the premises of the question – $6$-regular and even number of vertices – but has no spanning $3$-regular subgraph. This is easy to see by the handshaking lemma applied to each connected component.

Comment: Even number of vertices ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit The disjoint union of two $K_7$'s has $14$ vertices.

Comment: Oh ! Of course, you are right ... In which case the OP needs to add the connected condition ... this seems much harder ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yea... I've been struggling to find a counter example for the last half hour. I see no reason to believe a $6$-regular connected graph has a $3$-factor, but Tutte's $f$-factor theorem seems difficult to work with, at least for me :P

Comment: @Hendrix Might be easier to try a $4$ regular graph with a Hamiltonian cycle ... Indeed the (well known, lol) Crispin Nash-Williams conjecture counter example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meredith_graph